# Reading "*" with ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read the columns from a text file which look like

`name number1*number2`

why something like

```
Float_t value=0;
ifstream ifs("values.dat");
string line;
while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line from ifs
{
    istringstream iss(line); // access line as a stream
    string dataname;
    ifs >> dataname >> value; // no need to read further
```

but it fails to read the "*number2" part ie it passes to `xs` only the `number1` value. How can I fix this ?

Comment: What is a `Float_t`, and how does it override `operator>>`?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of whitespace around the operator you can read the asterisk as a single `char`:

```
int number1, number2;
char op;
iss >> number1 >> op >> number2;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/XOmXwh)